# Error al insertar decimales en SQL Server Management 2014

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, sql-server-2014

Al tratar de insertar decimales con punto `22.5` desde el visualstudio 2015 me aparece este error:

> `InnerException = {"Error converting data type varchar to decimal."}`.

El input donde ingreso el numero es de `type="number"`, y los datos se envian por ajax al controlador de esta manera:

```js
function InsertOrder() {

var datos =
     {

         pOrder: {

             Total: parseFloat($("#iptCost").val())
         }
     };
            console.log(datos);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(datos),
                url: urlInsertOrder,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {

                    //Validar data para ver si mostrar error al guardar o exito al guardar
                    if (result == true) {
                        $('#ModalSuccess').modal('toggle');
                    } else {
                        $('#modalFail').modal('toggle');
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("error");
                },

            });
}
```

En el controlador llegan los datos y le aplico un `Convert.ToDecimal()` para luego mandarlo a la capa de negocios y después al acceso a datos para que lo inserte en la BD.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertOrder(Order pOrder)
    {
        BusinessLogic.lnOrder _LNO = new BusinessLogic.lnOrder();
        Convert.ToDecimal(pOrder.Total);
        return Json(_LNO.InsertOrder(pOrder));
    }
```

Si le quito en el input la condición de `Type="Number"` y en vez de usar un punto para decimal y uso una coma el valor no da ningun error, pero si ingreso `22,22` en la bd aparece `22,00`.

```
public int InsertOrder(Order pOrder)
    {
        string sql = @"[spInsertOrder] '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}'";
        sql = string.Format(sql, pOrder.User.Id, pOrder.Quantity, pOrder.Total, pOrder.Type.Id, pOrder.Status.Id, pOrder.CreationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            pOrder.CreatorUser, pOrder.ModificationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), pOrder.ModificationUser);
        try
        {
            return _MB.EjecutarSQL(_CN, sql);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
    }
```

Este es el SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertOrder] 
Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @IdUser int
       ,@Quantity int
       ,@Total decimal(9,2)
       ,@IdType int
       ,@IdStatus int
       ,@CreationDate datetime
       ,@CreatorUser int
       ,@ModificationDate datetime
       ,@ModificationUser int
    AS
   BEGIN
 --SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order]
       ([IdUser]
       ,[Quantity]
       ,[Total]
       ,[IdType]
       ,[IdStatus]
       ,[CreationDate]
       ,[CreatorUser]
       ,[ModificationDate]
       ,[ModificationUser])
     VALUES
       (@IdUser
       ,@Quantity
       ,@Total
       ,@IdType
       ,@IdStatus
       ,@CreationDate
       ,@CreatorUser
       ,@ModificationDate
       ,@ModificationUser)

     select @@IDENTITY
    END
```

Comment: Deberías mostrar el método`InsertOrder`, necesitamos ver como estás haciendo el insert.

Comment: ¿El objeto `pOrder` llega con los decimales correctos? o se pierden en `InsertOrder(Order)`, si es este segundo caso, es imposible ayudarte sin que dejes la definición de este método?

Comment: Ya subi como hace el insertar. Y si, en el metodo ajax, llegan los decimales, en el metodo del controlador llegan los numeros con decimales, en la capa de logica igual, en todas esta llegando el numero con decimal.

Comment: @GregoriSalazar usar `String.format` para armar tu consulta no es una buena práctica en absoluto, por un lado, es muy inseguro, ademas, si el decimal llega bien, usando `SqlParameter ` es muy posible que tu problema se solucione, ya que la misma clase se encargará de formatear el decimal de modo correspondiente

Comment: mmm.. y el SP anda correctamente si lo llamas en la db? pq estas pasando todo como varchar...

Comment: que tipo de dato defines la propiedad Total en la clase Order  ?

Comment: el hecho de ingresas 22,22 y que se registre 22,00 no tiene que ver con el sistema de puntuacion, sino que defines incorrecto la precision del campo en la tabla

Comment: El problema parece claro. Si usaras consultas parametrizadas, el error no se produciría

Comment: La clase Order la propiedad Total esta definida como decimal. Por lo que me dicen es que en el `String.format` estoy pasando todos los datos a varchar. En el pOrder.Total cuando veo la informacion que tiene me aparece `22.22` pero cuando inspecciono en el `return _MB.EjecutarSQL(_CN, sql);` en el sql el total aparece como `22,72`. El punto lo cambio por una coma.

Comment: Cree una variable `decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(pOrder.Total)` la cual usaba en el Insert del DataAccess. A la variable total le agrege `.ToString().Replace(',', '.')` ya que luego de pasar por `sql = string.Format` se le cambiaba el punto por una coma. Asi me funciono y me registro el valor en la BD. Ya sera luego que haga cambios y mejoras correspondientes a mi proyecto entero . Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema viene debido a esta línea que está en tu controlador `InsertOrder`:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(pOrder.Total);
```

Haces una conversión a `decimal` pero no se la asignas a ninguna otra variable, se queda en el limbo esa conversión.

Lo ideal será que la propiedad `Total` de la clase `Order` sea de tipo `decimal` (`public decimal Total { get; set; }`). Si por cualquier razón no puedes modificar esa clase, tendrás que declarar una nueva variable y posteriormente enviarla a tu `Stored Procedure`:

```
public int InsertOrder(Order pOrder)
{
   decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(pOrder.Total);

    string sql = @"[spInsertOrder] '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}'";
    sql = string.Format(sql, pOrder.User.Id, pOrder.Quantity, total, pOrder.Type.Id, pOrder.Status.Id, pOrder.CreationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        pOrder.CreatorUser, pOrder.ModificationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), pOrder.ModificationUser);
    try
    {
        return _MB.EjecutarSQL(_CN, sql);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hice lo del `decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(pOrder.Total);` pero me sigue mostrando el error. 

En la clase Order ya tengo la propiedad `Total` de tipo `decimal`, igual en la BD y en el Stored Procedure.

Comment: @GregoriSalazar revisa qué valor llevas en esa variable, que no sea nulo y que sea un dato que se pueda castear a decimal

Comment: No llega nulo, llega el valor correcto, pero me di cuenta al ver la informacion que llega al `sql` que esta en la parte `return _MB.EjecutarSQL(_CN, sql);` del try, que alli se cambia el punto por una coma. Arriba en `total` llega `22.72` y cuando va al `return _MB.EjecutarSQL(_CN, sql);` en el try aparece como `22,72`

Comment: @GregoriSalazar entonces tendrás que normalizar el uso de cantidades monetarias para que esté igual tanto en el IDE como en la base de datos

Comment: A la variable `total` le agrege `.ToString().Replace(',', '.')`  ya que como mencione luego de pasar por `sql = string.Format` se le cambiaba el punto por una coma. Asi me funciono y me registro el valor en la BD. Ya sera luego que haga cambios y mejoras correspondientes a mi proyecto entero . Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Como la manera en la que estoy desarrollando mi codigo hice lo siguiente:

A la variable `total` que se encuentra en el insertar le agrege `.ToString().Replace(',', '.')` ya que luego de pasar por `sql = string.Format` se le cambiaba el punto por una coma y el sql server no lo ingresaba, he ahi el error.

```
public int InsertOrder(Order pOrder)
{
  decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(pOrder.Total);

string sql = @"[spInsertOrder] '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}'";
sql = string.Format(sql, pOrder.User.Id, pOrder.Quantity, total.ToString().Replace(',', '.'), pOrder.Type.Id, pOrder.Status.Id, pOrder.CreationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    pOrder.CreatorUser, pOrder.ModificationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), pOrder.ModificationUser);
try
{
    return _MB.EjecutarSQL(_CN, sql);
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    throw err;
}
```

}

Cabe a destacar tambien, que estoy usando ajax para pasar los datos desde mi vista al controlador usando `JSON.stringify()`. A los `input` que contengan los `values` con decimales les hago un `parseFloat` y dichos `input` son de tipo `number` para que solo se ingresen numeros y punto.

```
function InsertDoorsxUser() {
```

var datos =
         {

```
         pOrder:{
             Total: parseFloat($("#inputTotal")),
         },
     };
            console.log(datos);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(datos),
                url: urlInsertDoorsxUser,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {


                    if (result == true) {
                        $('#ModalSuccess').modal('toggle');
                    } else {
                        $('#ModalFail').modal('toggle');
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("errorFatal");
                },

            });
```

}